Can't add new line in Eric IDE
I cannot add a new line in the code editor of Eric IDE.
If I press Return or Shift+Return, nothing happens.
Some (possibly important) details on the installation:
eric7: 24.11
python: 3.10.12
Qt: 6.7.3
Operation system: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia with kernel 5.15.0-122-generic and desktop Cinnamon 6.0.4
